# Finding whether file is being copied or not in C++(in Windows)?

Tags: windows, file-copying, boost-filesystem, file-attributes

I want to figure out whether a given file is being copied or not. Initially I thought of doing fopen(_file) as fopen returns false while file is getting copied. But this idea fails when the file is opened in some applications(eg: when ppt is opened in MS powerpoint, fopen returns false). I'm in search of attributes of a file which uniquely identifies that the file is getting copied or not. I couldn't find such attributes even in boost::filesystem. Is this problem solvable using Boost lib? can someone help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

boost filesystem fstream utility solved this issue

> ```
>             boost::filesystem::fstream fileStream(filePath, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
>
>
>             if(fileStream.is_open())
>             {
>                 //not getting copied
>
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 //getting copied
>             }
> ```